# Activation Function NNET

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, activation-function, nnet

I've created a neural network using caret and nnet. 
Now, I need to deploy the NN in oracle for production. 
I already have the weights for each input and hidden layers.
However, I'm not sure which was the activation function used. Is there any way to know? Or do you know an easier way to do this task?

This is code I used to develop the NN:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 10)

nnet <- train(as.factor(TARGET) ~.-CONTRACT-MONTH-CUSTOMER,
                 data=stab_train_opt_norm,
                 method = "nnet",
                trControl = fitControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `nnet` documentation in R:

> One could use either a linear or a logistic activation/transfer fucntion in nnet. This could be specified by 'linout = TRUE' for linear and 'linout = FALSE' for logistic activation function. Default is logistic.